# How to include tab contents in spring when using tabbed form

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

I am trying to create a registration page that is using a tabbed view.

It was working perfectly fine when I tried to include all the tab contents inside respective tabs in single page.

Later I wrote the contents of each tab to different jsp pages specifically for each tab and tried to include the jsp pages using

But now all the jsp pages' contents are being listed under a single tab. I mean each tab is displaying contents of other tabs too.

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="reg-panel">

                    <ul id="breadcrumbs-one" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#main">Basic
                                Details</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Grade Details</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Facilities</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Awards</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Documents</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#preview">Preview</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#submit">Submit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">

                        <div id="main" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                            <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/basic_details.jsp" />
 </div>

                        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade">
                            <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/grade_details.jsp" />
   </div>

                        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">                               
                             <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/grade_details.jsp" />
   </div>

        .......             and so and so   ......
```

The problem here is that the contents of all the tabs basic details, grade details, awards and all such is being displayed under one tab itself.

Please help me resolve this. Which method should I actually have used? Is it better to use jstl or spring url instead?

Answer (score 0):

First get the list in spring controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/registration" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView registration(ModelAndView model)
{   
    List<Registration> regList = regService.regList();
    model.addObject("regList ", regList);
    model.setViewName("registration");
    setBreadCrumb(model);
    return model;
}

Now the list is added using model.addObject("regList ", regList);
```

Use the regList in jsp using JSTL you can do

```
<c:if test="${regList.grade=="something"}">
 show this
</c:if>
<c:if test="${regList.facilities=="something-else"}">
 show that
</c:if>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you got me wrong. All I want is to display different html forms for different tabs. (as in bootstrap tabs and pills) It dont have to match any conditions like you have mentioned here.

Comment: Then you can do something like this.                                                         
            <div class="foo-links float-left">
             <a href="/aboutUs">About Us</a>
            </div>
            <div class="foo-links float-left">
                <a href="/contactUs">Contact Us</a> 
            </div>                                                                                     
 Here each href is a call to a controller method which will render your pages with appropriate data

Comment: Thanks I will try that out.